# AJAX requests in Backbone

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Is there a way to avoid all the explicit AJAX requests `$.ajax()`  I seem to have to make when using Backbone?

I use AJAX to get templates from the server and for all sorts of other things, it seems kinda ghetto.

```
if (this.template == null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'static/html/ejs/homeTemplate.ejs',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(msg) {
            var ret = EJS.render(msg, {
                title: 'Welcome to the jungle',
                //filename: '/static/html/ejs/indexEJSTemplate.ejs'
            });
            self.$el.html(ret);
            //$('body').append(ret);
            console.log('HomeView rendered');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('error:', err);
        }
    });
} else {
    var ret = EJS.render(this.template, {
        title: 'Welcome to the jungle',
        //filename: '/static/html/ejs/indexEJSTemplate.ejs'
    });
    self.$el.html(ret);
    //$('body').append(ret);
    console.log('HomeView rendered');
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a module system and simply requiring them in?

Comment: no i haven't, that seems like a good option

Comment: i am using requirejs so yeah i could do that

Comment: using "text!" prefix will tell require to load the "text" module: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text  the specific plugin it uses is here: https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: You shouldn't have to make any explicit ajax requests if you are using models and collections and `.fetch` & `.save`. For locale modules you can use RequireJS and to load templates you use the text plugin, or a plugins for a particular template system which is usually built on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid AJAX calls for the following:

1. Retrieving templates from the server
2. Retrieving CSS from the server

by using the text plugin for RequireJS:

https://github.com/requirejs/text

if you are not using RequireJS, there are surely similar tools for Angular, Webpack and Browserify, that can include templates/CSS and other text based files in your build, whether it's for development or production.